# python Pandas replace the word in the string

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like:

```
A    B    C
1    a    yes
2    b    yes
3    a    no
```

I would like to change the dataframe to:

```
A    B    C
1    a    yes
2    b    no
3    a    no
```

which means that if column B has the value 'b', I want to change the column C to 'no'. Which can be represented by `df[df['B']=='b']['C'].str.replace('yes','no')`. But use this will not change dataframe `df` itself. Even I tried `df[df['B']=='b']['C'] = df[df['B']=='b']['C'].str.replace('yes','no')` it didn't work. I am wondering how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions with set values by `mask`:

```
df.loc[df.B == 'b', 'C'] = 'no'
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  a  yes
1  2  b   no
2  3  a   no

df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df.B == 'b','no')
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  a  yes
1  2  b   no
2  3  a   no
```

Solutions with replace only `yes` string:

```
df.loc[df.B == 'b', 'C'] = df['C'].replace('yes', 'no')
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  a  yes
1  2  b   no
2  3  a   no

df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df.B == 'b', df['C'].replace('yes', 'no'))
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  a  yes
1  2  b   no
2  3  a   no
```

Difference better seen in changed `df`:

```
print (df)
   A  B        C
0  1  a      yes
1  2  b      yes
2  3  b  another
3  4  a       no

df['C_set'] = df['C'].mask(df.B == 'b','no')
df['C_replace'] = df['C'].mask(df.B == 'b', df['C'].replace('yes', 'no'))

print (df)
   A  B        C C_set C_replace
0  1  a      yes   yes       yes
1  2  b      yes    no        no
2  3  b  another    no   another
3  4  a       no    no        no
```

EDIT:

In your solution is necessary only add `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'] = df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'].str.replace('yes','no')
print (df)
   A  B        C
0  1  a      yes
1  2  b       no
2  3  b  another
3  4  a       no
```

EDIT1:

I was really curious what method is fastest:

```
#[40000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)    
print (df)

In [37]: %timeit df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'] = df['C'].str.replace('yes','no')
10 loops, best of 3: 79.5 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'] = df.loc[df['B']=='b','C'].str.replace('yes','no')
10 loops, best of 3: 48.4 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'] = df.loc[df['B']=='b', 'C'].replace('yes','no')
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df.B == 'b', df['C'].replace('yes', 'no'))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop

# piRSquared solution with replace
In [53]: %timeit df.C = np.where(df.B.values == 'b', df.C.replace('yes', 'no'), df.C.values)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.74 ms per loop
```

EDIT1:

Better is change condition - add `df.C == 'yes'` or `df.C.values == 'yes'` if need fastest solution:

```
df.loc[(df.B == 'b') & (df.C == 'yes'), 'C'] = 'no'

df.C = np.where((df.B.values == 'b') & (df.C.values == 'yes'), 'no', df.C.values)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact my case is a little difficult than what I have showed. I will try the methods you introduced first.

Comment: there shouldn't be a need to use `df.C.replace`.  When `df.B.values=='b'`, we'll be making `df.C` `no`... the replace uses excess cpu when logically it isn't needed.

Comment: In fact in the original dataframe C is a column of strings with each value contains specific words like 'yes' or 'no'. Such as "yes, it is"

Comment: @natsuapo - I am thinking about better solution - check last edit.

Comment: @jezrael, what if you want 1 word out of an entire pandas dataframe to match. For example, say I my string in row 1 of the dataframe says "Hello Nancy, what is a good number to reach you?" and I want to replace "a" with " ". When I run the above code, I get "Hello Nncy, wht is  good number" instead of just getting rid of a. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @mkheifetz - do you try `df['C'].str.replace('a',' ')` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the quick response! That's exactly what I tried, and it gives me the output I wrote above. It removes every "a" from my dataframe instead of only removing every place where "a" is just the 1 letter word

Comment: @mkheifetz - hmm, so need `df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r"\ba\b",' ')`, it is called word boundary

Answer (score 4):

**[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**

```
df.C = np.where(df.B == 'b', 'no', df.C)
```

Or

```
df.C = np.where(df.B.values == 'b', 'no', df.C.values)
```

**[`pd.Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)**

```
df.C = df.C.mask(df.B == 'b', 'no')
```

---

All change `df` in place and yield

```
   A  B    C
0  1  a  yes
1  2  b   no
2  3  a   no
```

---

***timing***  [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try `where` as well.